# Expanding size of virtual hard drive (ZFS)

Tags: debian, vmware-workstation, zfs

I am using Debian Jessie in VMWare workstation with one virtual hard drive.

On /dev/sda1 I have a /boot on /dev/sda2 I have / and on /dev/sda3 I have swap and /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 I had in ZFS mirrored pool (together about 4.7 GB) and have mounted /home on zfs_pool/home all is running OK, but I have following scenario: Capacity on my mirrored pool is running out and I want to increase capacity of mirrored pool, but first: my virtual disks capacity.

[image: ZFS]

As shown in the picture above I expand virtual hard drive up to 10GB and with gparted created /dev/sda7 partition, from zfs_pool I detached /dev/sda5, attach /dev/sda7 and resilvering data from /dev/sda6 to /dev/sda7 and then I detached /dev/sda6 too, because now I want to increase capacity of my mirrored tank I need to create (from /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6) one partition and attach it to /dev/sda7 as mirror (it is recommended way to increase the capacity of mirrored pool?)

Now my pool is not in mirror state, it consists only from /dev/sda7, but if I want to delete /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 my partition /dev/sda7 will now have name /dev/sda5 and when I reboot zfs doesnt recognize my pool, here is output of zdb and from fdisk -l

[image: ZDB and fdisk]

As you can see path is still /dev/sda7, but I have /dev/sda5, where are (I think) correct data, any solution to replace this path? Or simply create only new mirrored pool with /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 from unallocated space?

Thank for your answer and have a nice day.

Comment: I sincerely hope you’re just experimenting, because that setup is incredible. And by incredible I mean bad. You gain no benefits whatsoever (well, except double the IO) by putting both vdevs of a mirror on the same disk.

Answer (score 1):

**Best way to Increase Capacity**
The best way to increase the capacity of a pool is to add a `vdev` to the pool. If this isn't and option then you can go about replacing the drives in a `resilver -> replace -> resilver` fashion.

**What Happened in your Config**:
Linux sets the partition names based on the number of partitions, in your case you had 7 partitions thus you had names `sda1..7`. But when you merged the two partitions this decreased your partition count, resulting in names `sda1..5`. This is why it it a good idea to add drives based on a unique identifier, for in the event that the `sda` name changes ZFS can still locate it.

**How to Fix This Issue**:
If you run a `zpool import` it should be able to find the previously built pool on what was `/dev/sda7` and is now `/dev/sda5`. You will more then likely get an output like the fallowing:

```
# zpool import

  pool: dozer
  id: 2704475622193776801
  state: ONLINE
  action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
  config:
    dozer       ONLINE
      c1t9d0    ONLINE
```

I you get this first attempt importing by pool ID with `zpool import 2704475622193776801`. If this is unsuccessful you may have to rename the pool by importing it as a different name with the command `zpool import old_name new_name`.

**Note**:
In your first picture the `zpool status` shows:

```
NAME:       STATE     READ  WRITE  CKSUM
zfs_pool    ONLINE       0      0      0
    sda7    ONLINE       0      0      0
```

In this config there is no `mirror` vdev. By adding your newly merged partition to this pool it will not be mirroring the drives but rather what is called a `dynamic stripe` essentially a `RAID 0`. In order to create a mirror you will probably need to recreate the pool. Good Luck, Hope this Helps!

**Source**:
[Importing ZFS Storage Pools](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gazuf/index.html)